# Stuck trying to link up pages

Tags: java, android-layout

I got the first-page working but got a youtube tutorial for the second but can't seem to get it working the way I want it to.the pages are done differently.

## This is the working page

```
private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
            //Loop all child item of Main Grid
            for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
                //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
                CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
                final int finalI = i;
                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                       if (finalI == 0) // open page 1
                       {
                           Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, StarterVapes.class);
                           startActivity(intent);
                       }

                       else if (finalI == 1) // open page 2
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, UpgradeVapes.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

## This is the nonworking page

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(imagesList.get(i));
        viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(titleList.get(i));
        final int finalI = i;
        viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (finalI == 0) // open page 1
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent (context, AboutUS.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

                else if (finalI == 1) // open page 2
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent (context.this, AboutUS.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

              //  Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
              //  intent.putExtra("title", titleList.get(i));
              //  context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I want it to were you click on the first tile it goes to a page, you click on the second tile it goes to a different page and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
          Got it working
```

### Heading

`````
           ````
             if (finalI == 0) // open page 1
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent (context, AboutUS.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", titleList.get(i));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
           ````
`````